# How to further refine the BeautifulSoup Data (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pydev

I want to refine soup's data in a way that 
    1. Refine data on the basis of `sou.findAll("div", class_="span-24")`
    2. Then refine the data further and find all links having `href` values.
    I am running the code given below.

```
import re
import urllib.request 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://tribune.com.pk/"

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'})
htm = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
sou = BeautifulSoup(htm,"html.parser")


data = sou.findAll("div", class_="span-24")

for link in data:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

but it is giving `none` in output.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The *href* would be in the *anchor* tag, you are trying to pull it from the actual div:

```
link.a.get('href'))
```

But not  every *div* with the class *span-24* has an anchor tag, you can use a css selector to find the anchor tags  that are inside the divs:

```
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://tribune.com.pk/"

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'})
htm = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htm,"html.parser")


data = soup.select("div.span-24 a[href]")

for a in data:
    print(a["href"])
```

That actually gives you quite a lot of links, you might want to be more specific as to which part of the html you actually want the links from.